# Bug in if statement

Tags: c++

No matter what string I add to s[i], I I still get a "yes" as an output while if I remove ||(OR) it works perfectly.

```
for(int i=0; i<T; i++)
  {
    if(s[i]=="ccc"||"ccs")
    {
        cout<<"yes"<<endl;
    }
    else
    {
        cout<<"no"<<endl;
    }
```

Comment: What do you think this means: `"ccc"||"ccs"`?

Comment: What's `s`? Learn how to ask acceptable quality questions, please.

Comment: You need to write a complete statement on each side of the `||` operator; that is `if (something == value_1 || something == value_2)`.

Comment: @tambre in this case it is quite clear that `s` has no bearing on the question.The issue is OP doesn't understand how compound logic statements work properly. I think this is a perfectly acceptable question, albeit that it is a duplicate

Comment: Hi Sarvesh, and welcome to Stack Overflow! Please ignore the downvotes - some people here can be a bit quick to judge "newbie" questions. Hopefully the linked duplicate question, and the existing answers and comments give you an insight into the problem with your code.

Comment: @SteveLorimer Thanks for the answer, I got the error now thanks a ton.

Answer (score 1):

This is how it's written:

```
if(s[i] == "ccc" || s[i] == "ccs")
```

Comment: And an explanation of why this works, but his doesn't work?

Answer (score 1):

Change your if condition to:

```
if(s[i] == "ccc" || s[i] == "ccs")
```